# php sessions dont seem to work

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am new to php. I have tried to use php session variables in my login page so that when I once login and then logout, I dont see the same details I entered during login.but even when i used sessions,it does not seem to work and when I go back I see the same details,help anyone.

```
<?php

session_start();


?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Alfalah Banking
        </title>
    </head>
            <body>

            <form action='emp_form.php' method='post'>
            <table width='400' align='center' border='5'>
            <tr>

                <td align='center' colspan="5" bgcolor="orange">
                Login
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th align='right'>
                Password    
                </th>
                <td>
                <input type='text' name='password'>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='6' align='center'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php


$connection=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
@mysql_select_db("bank_db",$connection);



if (isset($GET['logout'])){
session_start();
session_destroy();

}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $query="select * from per_emp_cash where Password='$password'";
    $run=mysql_query($query);

    $query=mysql_num_rows($run) ;





    if(mysql_num_rows($run)==1)
    {
         $_SESSION['Current'] = $password;
      echo "You are logged in succefully";
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<a href='cashier_detail.php?password=$password'>View your Profile</a>";
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<a href='caashier.php?password=$password'>Make Account</a>";





    }


    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Invalid user name or password')</script>";

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Try to print variables after adding them to session. And your site looks quit vulnerable to `SQL Injection`

Comment: how please give me full detail

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you are not using the session even though you assigned a value to it.

Comment: on back click it will still show the previous pages

Comment: And also it is not advisable to use passwords and similar data with URLs as Params. Good tutorial on how to create a php login page can be found http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: @NayabAli back button suppose to do that right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the sequence of the code blocks in your file. First handle the PHP dynamic processing, then display the static content. In other words, move the HTML block to the end of your file.

And always stick to this rule: dynamic processing first, then static content. In the future it will help you to understand how frameworks work and how to avoid re-sending the same data twice, etc.